# How to provide unique TokenId to NonFungibleToken's mint function?

Tags: nearprotocol

How to provide unique TokenId to NonFungibleToken's mint function, UUID?
How to have auto-increment id in the contract code?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the use case of the NFT.  The only requirement is that it is unique and the mint will fail otherwise.

The increment approach you mention is the easiest if the id isn't important.  But otherwise you could use hashes encoded in base58 or base64. Again it all really depends on the use case.

For example, in https://github.com/willemneal/tenk, it's a set of ids that get chosen from with each mint.

Comment: for increment approach, can I keep last_mint_id in the contract? Do I need to take care race condition? I have look into tenk, but not quite understand how Raffle works.

Comment: You don't have to worry about race conditions.  Each function call on the contract is atomic. You can keep another variable in the contract state, or just have the id be the current number of tokens minted (assuming that they can't be burned).

The raffle is a way to randomly pick a number from a range of numbers.  As one number is removed you can't pick it again; rather pick from the rest.